# date_create_from_format accepts invalid dates as an input

Tags: php, parsing, date

PHP `date_create_from_format` function is accepting non-existent, though format-valid dates.

I would like this function to behave like the `date` command:

```
niloct@HP-Mini:~$ date --date="29/02/2011" +%s
date: invalid date `29/02/2011'
```

though this is what happens in php:

```
$tmp = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s',"29/02/2011 00:00:00", timezone_open('America/Sao_Paulo'));
var_dump($tmp);
/*
output: object(DateTime)#28 (3) { ["date"]=> string(19) "2011-03-01 00:00:00" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(17) "America/Sao_Paulo" }
*/
```

Can this automatic conversion be avoided and the function return `-1` in this case ?

```
niloct@HP-Mini:~$ php -v
PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jan 12 2011 16:08:14)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that calling `date_get_last_errors` after `date_create_from_format` already gives you all kind of validations on the parsed string, in the arrays `warnings` and `errors`, and counters `warning_count` and `error_count`.

So just checking the counters for zero warnings and errors is enough.

Revised code with some tests:

```
<?
$appTZ = 'America/Sao_Paulo';

function datetimeCreateErrorsWarnings() {
    $obj = date_get_last_errors();  
    return ($obj['error_count'] > 0) || ($obj['warning_count'] > 0);
}

function datetimeToUnixTS($data) {
    global $appTZ;

    $fmt = "d/m/Y H:i:s";

    $dtobj = date_create_from_format($fmt, $data . " 00:00:00", timezone_open($appTZ)); 

    if ($dtobj) {
        if (!datetimeCreateErrorsWarnings()) {
            return date_timestamp_get($dtobj);
        }
    }

    //Second try, $data is auto-suficient
    $dtobj = date_create_from_format($fmt, $data, timezone_open($appTZ));

    if ($dtobj) {
        if (!datetimeCreateErrorsWarnings()) {
            return date_timestamp_get($dtobj);
        }
    }

    return -1;
}

$test = array(
    'asdfasdf',
    '',
    "28/02/2011",
    "29/02/2011",
    "28/02/2011 00:00:90"
);

for ($i=0; $i<count($test); $i++) {
    $tmp = datetimeToUnixTS($test[$i]);
    var_dump($tmp);
    echo "<p>";
}
?>
```

The above script calculates the unix timestamp of the datetime created.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a combination of [`date_parse_from_format`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) and [`checkdate`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) to see if it's a valid calendar date.

Example:

```
$date = date_parse_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s',"29/02/2011 00:00:00");

if (checkdate($date['month'], $date['day'], $date['year'])) {
    echo "Valid date";
}
else {
    echo "Invalid date";
}
```

Comment: I see. But how do I parse with timezones ?

Comment: @Niloct: You don't, because timezones don't come into parsing. February 29, 2011 does not exist in any timezone. **After** you make sure the date is valid, call `date_create_from_format` with a timezone, as in your code.

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
 $format = 'd/m/Y H:i';
   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, Input::get('start_date'));

  return $date->format('Y/m/d H:i');
```